# Your manifest does not contain permission com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID

Tags: android, google-play-console, google-advertising-id

I have a problem with uploading the latest version of my app to the Google Play store.

My application does not have any ads but it uses Firebase and `com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID` is put into the merged manifest. That's why I declared in the "App Content > Advertising ID" form that my app uses advertising ID for analytics.

However, I am now getting the following error:

> Your advertising ID declaration in Play Console says that your app uses advertising ID. A manifest file in one of your active artifacts doesn't include the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission.

This is not true because my manifest has it and also I have tried to put it in my manifest manually. But no luck. Still the same error.

On the other hand, when I update that the "App Content > Advertising ID" form to say that my application does not use advertising ID then I getting the following error:

> This release includes the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission but your declaration on Play Console says your app doesn't use advertising ID.

What should I do? Whatever I select, the error pops in.

Comment: I am facing this exact same problem despite using the latest versions of the `com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-gradle` and `com.google.gms:google-services` build tools (i.e. `2.9.7` and `4.3.15` at the time of writing) and the latest version of the `com.google.firebase:firebase-bom` library (i.e. `32.2.0` at the time of writing).

Comment: Update: I'm starting to think that this error is a bug in the Google Play Console. My reasoning is as follows: I have two Android apps which use identical build tools and libraries. I get the advertising ID error for one of these apps and not the other.

Answer (score 3):

I reached out to Google support and this is the solution:

1. Go to the App Content tab.
2. Click the Advertising ID.
3. You'll see the "Turn off release errors" at the bottom part.

Strange! but worked for me

Comment: Where is it (App Content tab) ?

Comment: On The left panel in app console

Comment: Turning off release errors requires the following declaration: "I understand the ramifications of not including the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission in the manifest file when targeting Android 13 and would like to turn off release errors". That's somewhat terrifying.

Comment: Update: I decided to "Turn off release errors" in the "App Content > Advertising ID" form. I saw no other path forward.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. I don't know how to fix it, but I have the following observation: in my case, the result depends on which SDK I target when I build the code. (sic!). So, precisely:

- my app does not have any ads
- some external dependancy adds AD_ID to the merged manifest
- in Google Play -> App Content -> Ads I have 'app does not contain ads'

Now if I compile the app targeting SDK 32, then the merged Manifest does contain AD_ID but when I upload this to the Play Store, Google does not complain about anything.
If I however compile the very same thing targeting SDK 33, the resulting Manifests looks identical to me (still contains AD_ID) but when I try uploading that, Google complains that I declare no ads in the app but in the Manifest there's AD_ID.

Comment: thanks for sharing this I posted solution that I got from Google

Comment: Thanks - this indeed helps. Can I ask how did you contact Google that you got an answer from them? My attempts have been futile.

Comment: via Google Play console